# How to add custom data in admin dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

My module have product questions.

Now i want to display latest 5 question in dashboard using my custom module

[image]

How can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to rewrite this block to do it.

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard

<global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <dashboard>Spacename_Modulname_Block_Adminhtml_Dashboard</dashboard>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

below function add your template file and show your block

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('dashboard/index.phtml');

    }
```

Comment: in index.phtml i can write only my code or i have to copy core phtml code than add my code?

Comment: core phtml + your code

Comment: and in this block extends ??
Test_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Dashboard extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard ri8??

Comment: yes you are right